# domain redirect on another domain that has SSL

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, redirect

how can i set domain redirect on another domain that has SSL security certificate?

i tried for redirect properly. i used htaccess code, i wrote all type code but i could't. please help me.my primary domain has SSL security certificate, so i can't redirect another domain on this domain.i could't set Add-on domain or aliases domain for redirect of this domain also.

it show security alert and stop redirect. what is the problem?can someone give me best solution or codes?

Comment: Given that the second domain you want seems to be zakariaco.ir  you need to first configure the domain properly so that it is actually reachable.  Currently there is no IP address associated with this domain so a redirect will not work since there is nothing to redirect too yet.

Comment: pls help me more clear. thanks

Comment: I have no idea how to be more clear since I don't know what your knowledge is. But, assuming that you don't understand what I mean with that your domain has no IP address I guess that your knowledge is practically zero. In this case: please contact the one where you bought the domain from and your hosting provider since they need to help you to setup your system properly - you cannot do this fully by your own at this stage.

Comment: they said don't help me more .

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTPS_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^zakariaco\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTPS_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

try it.

Comment: no first one is for http to https and second one from https to http

Comment: put it on your website htaccess file

Comment: 2
3
 

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Comment: with or without aliases domain ??

Answer (score 0):

# Redirect HTTPS to HTTP

```
     RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =https
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: add this into yor htaccess

Comment: How many answer you want to write? you can edit your existing answer.

Comment: Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site.

We can’t connect to the server at www.zakariaco.ir.
If that address is correct, here are three other things you can try:

    Try again later.
    Check your network connection.
    If you are connected but behind a firewall, check that Firefox has permission to access the Web.